# problem with a very simple tile based game

Tags: tiles, tile, pacman

I am trying to create a pacman-like game. I have an array that looks like this:

array:

```
1111111111111
1000000000001
1111110111111
1000000000001
1111111111111
```

1 = Wall, 0 = Empty space

I use this array to draw tiles that are 16x16 in size.
The Game character is 32x32.

Initially I represented the character's position in array indexes, [1,1] etc.

I would update his position if array[character.new_y][charater.new_x] == 0

Then I translated these array coordinates to pixels, [y*16, x*16] to draw him.

He was lining up nicely, wouldn't go into walls, but I noticed that since I was updating him by 16 pixels each, he was moving very fast.

I decided to do it in reverse, to store the game character's position in pixels instead, so that he could use less than 16 pixels per move.

I thought that a simple if statement such as this:

```
if array[(character.new_pixel_y)/16][(character.new_pixel_x)/16] == 0
```

would prevent him from going into walls, but unfortunately he eats a bit of the bottom and right side walls.

Any ideas how would I properly translate pixel position to the array indexes? I guess this is something simple, but I really can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you appear to have transposed your 2D array. Was that on purpose?
(is it array[x][y] or array[y][x]?)

also, a game character of double the tile size would not fit in the example map array given!

edit:

if your character eats into the bottom and right by exactly half a tile and he/she doesn't overlap the top & right, then you need to offset your character by half a tile. (+/- 8 pixels to both x & y)

so when you, "translated these array coordinates to pixels, [y*16, x*16] to draw him."
you should change this to:
[(y*16)-8, (x*16)-8] to draw him when he is 32x32.

keep storing his position as [y*16, x*16], to follow the 16x convention.

this would be easier for you if you kept everything 16x16 first!

you should also store the tile_size_x & tile_size_y as a constant.

Comment: Hi, the 16x16 tiles are half empty, so the game character fits between them (although he technically overlaps a part of them). As for the array, sorry, it was my stupid naming convention.

Comment: Ah! indeed, I was trying the entire day with centering by 16 pixels and it all would screw up, centering it via 8 pixels, and then adjusting based on his top/left/right/bottom direction by 8px worked, thanks

Comment: drawing is done from top left and tiles are 16x bigger. and we know 32x tile should overlap by HALF a 16 size tile = 8 pixels. :)